# Which service should I use?

Tags: java, android, service

I got 2 classes: A(Activity subclass) which generates the phone location infinitely and class B (thread subclass) which takes the location from A and send it to the db.
Since it's an activity it's stop generating the locations once I close my application so I guess service would make the job.

I read about services in [here(http://developer.android.com)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

but I couldn't understand **which** service should I use and how?
The change that I'm planning to do is to turn A into a service and create class C(activity) which start & stop A.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Timer for this..

```
private void startservice() {

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {

public void run() {

//Do whatever you want to do every “INTERVAL”

}

}, 0, INTERVAL);

; }
```

Execute or call a method at a certain time.

You can read [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx) for more details.

Comment: It can run on the background?

Comment: timers are bad practice in android. use the alarm manager instead.

Comment: yes..it can run on the background and you can stop it in activity.